# Firebase Authentication Quota exceeded (auth/quota-exceeded)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I'm testing an app that uses firebase authentication free tier via the phone. I registered the phone I am using for testing as a fictional phone in the Firebase administration console taking into account the official instructions: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?hl= es&authuser=1#create-fictional-phone-numbers-and-verification-codes](https://I%27m%20testing%20an%20app%20that%20uses%20firebase%20authentication%20via%20the%20phone.%20I%20registered%20the%20phone%20I%20am%20using%20for%20testing%20as%20a%20dummy%20phone%20in%20the%20Firebase%20administration%20console%20taking%20into%20account%20the%20official%20instructions:%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?hl=%20es&authuser=1#create-fictional-phone-numbers-and-verification-codes.%20But%20when%20testing%20my%20application%20I%20get%20the%20following%20error:). But when testing my application I get the following error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Exceeded quota. (auth/quota-exceeded).
    at _errorWithCustomMessage (index-e3d5d3f4.js:476:20)
    at index-e3d5d3f4.js:908:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-backdrop_entry_js.js:2 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Exceeded quota. (auth/quota-exceeded).
FirebaseError: Firebase: Exceeded quota. (auth/quota-exceeded).
    at _errorWithCustomMessage (index-e3d5d3f4.js:476:20)
    at index-e3d5d3f4.js:908:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
    at zone.js:1257:36
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:10735:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:10735:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:11048:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
```

Any idea how can this be solved?!

I don't understand why I am exceeding the quota, if checking the usage quotas does not show that any limit has been reached. Also, how can I know precisely what limits I am exceeding or what is the exact reason for exceeding this quota?

EDIT

Let me share some code:

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MaskitoOptions, MaskitoElementPredicateAsync } from '@maskito/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-method',
  templateUrl: './phone-method.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-method.component.scss'],
})
export class PhoneMethodComponent  implements OnInit {
  phoneForm: FormGroup;
  phoneNumber: string;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNum: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\+\d{2}\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/)])
    ]});
    this.phoneNumber="";
  }

  async sendSMS() {
    this.phoneNumber=this.phoneForm.get('phoneNum')?.value;
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Enviando mensaje...',
      cssClass: 'custom-loading'
    });
    this.authService.signInWithPhoneNumber(this.phoneNumber,loading).then(result=>{
      loading.dismiss();
      let encodedPhoneNumber = encodeURIComponent(this.phoneNumber);
      this.router.navigate(['/phone-otp',encodedPhoneNumber]);
    });

    /*let phone=this.phoneForm.get('phoneNum')?.value;
    if (this.phoneForm.valid) {
      console.log(phone);
    }*/
  }

  goBack() {
    // Navigate one step back in the browser's history
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }

  readonly phoneMask: MaskitoOptions = {
    mask: ['+','5','7',' ','(',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,')',' ',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'-',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,/\d/],
  };

  readonly maskPredicate: MaskitoElementPredicateAsync = async (el) => (el as HTMLIonInputElement).getInputElement();

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

HTML:

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <a (click)="goBack()">&lt; Atrás</a>
  <h3 class="tittle">Ingresa tu número celular</h3>
  <p class="description">Te enviaremos un código para confirmarlo</p>
  <form [formGroup]="phoneForm" (ngSubmit)="sendSMS()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input class="margin-top"
        label="Número de celular"
        type="tel"
        class="custom"
        formControlName="phoneNum"
        labelPlacement="floating"
        placeholder="+57 (xxx) xxx-xxxx"
        [maskito]="phoneMask"
        [maskitoElement]="maskPredicate">
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
  <div class="ion-text-center margin-top">
    <ion-button type="submit" *ngIf="phoneForm.valid" fill="outline">Enviar SMS</ion-button>
  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

SERVICE:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth,signInWithEmailAndPassword,createUserWithEmailAndPassword,signInWithPhoneNumber,RecaptchaVerifier,signOut} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  appVerifier: any;
  confirmationResult: any;

  constructor(private _fireAuth: Auth) {
    _fireAuth.languageCode ='es';
    _fireAuth.settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting=true;
  }

  recaptcha(loading: HTMLIonLoadingElement) {
    this.appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: (response: any) => {
        loading.present();
      },
      'expired-callback': () => {
      }
    }, this._fireAuth);
  }

  async signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string, loading: HTMLIonLoadingElement) {
    try {
      if(!this.appVerifier){
        this.recaptcha(loading);
      }
      const confirmationResult = await signInWithPhoneNumber(this._fireAuth, phoneNumber, this.appVerifier);
      this.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      loading.dismiss();
      return confirmationResult;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
      throw(e);
    }
  }

  async verifyOtp(otp: any, loading: HTMLIonLoadingElement) {
    try {
      if(!this.appVerifier){
        this.recaptcha(loading);
      }
      const result = await this.confirmationResult.confirm(otp);
      const user = result?.user;
      loading.dismiss();
      return user;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  /*
    async register({ email, password }) {
        try {
            const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);
            return user;
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    async login({ email, password }) {
        try {
            const user = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password);
            return user;
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
    }*/

    logout() {
        return signOut(this._fireAuth);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the limit you potentially have exceeded: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone-auth

Comment: @aabdulahad I can assure you that I have not crossed any of these limits

Comment: If you think the quota is wrong, and you don't have code and debug details to share, there is nothing we can do to help.  Contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/) directly.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edit the question with some code